# Change telnet port of scrapy from [6023, 6073] to 80

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy, telnetlib

As we know Scrapy runs on port between 6023 to 6073.
But due to firewall these ports are blocked and I am abideby by it.
Now I am trying to change the port of scrapy.[image]

To something like 127.0.0.1:80.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrapy itself is a framework, it does not listen to anything per-se.

You seem to be refering to the [telnet console](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/telnetconsole.html).

See [`TELNETCONSOLE_PORT`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/telnetconsole.html#std:setting-TELNETCONSOLE_PORT) setting to change the port it listens to.

Something like this should do what you want:

```
TELNETCONSOLE_PORT = [80]
```

Comment: There is point of conflict with browser port. Its not working

Comment: Well, then you need to choose a port number that is allowed by your firewall and not 80. Your call here.